# Django running bash script when less file is modified

Tags: python, django, less

I wrote bash script converting *.less files into *.css using lessc.
Unfortunately run function from BaseRunserverCommand restarts server only, when *.py files was modified.
How can I solve this?

Comment: its not an answer, but did you considered using Django-Compressor (it contains this functionality)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct overriding [code_changed()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/autoreload.py#L55) function seemed a bit hard,so I decided to write my own script converting *.less files which was modified or had no *.css file.
This script is running in [reloader_thread()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/autoreload.py#L92):

```
import sys, time
from subprocess import call

from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import autoreload

from django.core.management.commands.runserver import Command

def convert_less():
    status = call([settings.CONVERT_LESS, settings.LESS_DIR, settings.CSS_DIR])
    if status != 0:
        exit(1)

def reloader_thread():
    autoreload.ensure_echo_on()
    while autoreload.RUN_RELOADER:
        convert_less()
        if autoreload.code_changed():
            sys.exit(3) # force reload
        time.sleep(1)

autoreload.reloader_thread = reloader_thread
```

Tadeck, thank you for clue :)

I suppose that this problem could be also solved by editing [BaseCommand.option_list](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py#L22)

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own command inheriting from [`django.core.management.commands.runserver.Command`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py#L21), overriding `run()` method with your own, which would use your own `autoreload`:

```
def run(self, *args, **options):
    """
    Runs the server, using the autoreloader if needed
    """
    use_reloader = options.get('use_reloader')

    if use_reloader:
        autoreload.main(self.inner_run, args, options)
    else:
        self.inner_run(*args, **options)
```

Your own instance of `autoreload`, however, would need to override only [`code_changed()` function](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/autoreload.py#L55) to take also `*.less` and `*.css` (or more) files into account.